Need advice with Applied Stats II R code error
I'm a total noob at R trying to complete a Stats II project. I keep getting the following error for the code below: [1] "Confusion Matrix: TRAINING set based on random forest model built using 2 trees"
Error in table(train.data$heart_data, train.data.predict): all arguments must have the same length
Traceback:

table(train.data$heart_data, train.data.predict)
stop("all arguments must have the same length")

set.seed(6522048)
library(randomForest)
model_rf1 <- randomForest(target ~ age+sex+cp+trestbps+chol+restecg+exang+ca, 
                          data = train.data, ntree = 2)
print("======================================================================================================================")
print('Confusion Matrix: TRAINING set based on random forest model built using 2 trees')
train.data.predict <- predict(model_rf1, train.data, type = "class")

conf.matrix <- table(train.data$heart_data, train.data.predict)[,c('YES','NO')]
rownames(conf.matrix) <- paste("Actual", rownames(conf.matrix), sep = ": ")
colnames(conf.matrix) <- paste("Prediction", colnames(conf.matrix), sep = ": ")

format(conf.matrix,justify="centre",digit=2)

print("=====================================================================================================================")
print('Confusion Matrix: TESTING set based on random forest model built using 2 trees')
test.data.predict <- predict(model_rf1, test.data, type = "class")

conf.matrix <- table(test.data$heart_data, test.data.predict)[,c('YES','NO')]
(conf.matrix) <- paste("Actual", rownames(conf.matrix), sep = ": ")
colnames(conf.matrix) <- paste("Prediction", colnames(conf.matrix), sep = ": ")

format(conf.matrix,justify="centre",digit=2)


This is hard without a reproducible example. Error in table(train.data$heart_data, train.data.predict): all arguments must have the same length : Have you tried comparing length(train.data$heart_data) to length(train.data.predict)?

Did you intend to write conf.matrix <- table(test.data$target, test.data.predict)?
